# Reading data from mongodb to spark using scala from docker. Getting 0 records, why?

Tags: mongodb, scala, docker, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Getting zero records when trying to load data to spark. printSchema shows root. I validated that the collection shows 24 records with multiple attributes.

Script:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.
    builder().
    appName("Spark SQL basic example").
    config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").
    getOrCreate();

val mongoServerName = "host.docker.internal:8081";
// val mongoServerName = "127.0.0.1:8081";
val mongoUsername = "xyz";
val mongoPassword = "xyz";
val mongoDbName = "mydb";
val mongoAuthDBName = "mydb";
val mongoCollection = "myCollection";
val mongoConnectionString = f"mongodb://$mongoUsername:$mongoPassword@$mongoServerName/$mongoDbName.$mongoCollection/?authSource=$mongoAuthDBName";
val mongoDf = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", mongoConnectionString).load()
mongoDf.show();
```

Output:

```
mongoDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []
++
||
++
++
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using a simple MongoDB on local container.

Try change `mongoAuthDBName` to `admin`. And try to use this code using [Mongo Spark connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/python-api/)

```py
df = spark.read.format("mongo") \
    .option("uri", f"mongodb://${mongoUsername}:${mongoPassword}@${mongoServerName}/${mongoDbName}.${mongoCollection}/?authSource=${mongoAuthDBName}&ssl=false") \
    .load()
```